# SQL - clearing execution cache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to profile a few queries but as you know, when you run a query a second time, it comes back in 0ms. I'm using

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick. what else can I run to clear any trace of execution/results cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC dropcleanbuffers;
```

This should not be run on a production server though. `CHECKPOINT` is a database scoped command that will write the dirty buffers to disc so they will be affected by the next command but `DBCC dropcleanbuffers` is global and all data pages dropped from the buffer cache in this manner will need to be read in from disc when used next time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also want to use DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.  This will test the queries with a cold buffer cache.

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```